# Possible to control or limit distance of gloss and shadow how it affects other objects?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, node-editor, light, shadows

I'm creating a scene with a room and I wonder if it possible, with the help of nodes, limit the distance of an objects shadow and glossy to nearby objects or as an alternative tell object A not to affect object B but affect the rest of the scene?

I have turned of glossy and shadow in the Cycles setting for an object because I didn't want it to affect another object and it looked nice, but then it affected the rest of the scene in a negative way.

Curious if this is possible?

Comment: Sounds like you shouldn't be using a physically based path tracer. Most of those kinds of interactions are generally not physically real and hence not easy to achieve in Cycles. Have a look at the [Light Path Node](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/cycles/nodes/types/input/light_path.html) though it may be a waste of resources to be rendering these things in a complex rayracer

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/96615/fade-out-reflection-in-mirror-with-cycles